# How to Make A contining Jquery Counter that increases by a number ever 24 hours

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm working on this jQuery counter that counts up and everything, but the client wants to be able to put in the number that the count starts at (currently 15,205,456) and then have the count increase by 1,500,000 hits daily (every 24 hours). This information needs to be added to WordPress as a Custom Field.  The code I have is this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('.count').each(function () {
          $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
             Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 8640000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toLocaleString('en'));
            }
       });
    });
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible with native JavaScript/jQuery.

Using JavaScript's `prompt` function, we can collect user input. To run a function after a set amount of time, we want to use the `setInterval` method. It's important to note that the time value passed in as the last parameter is in milliseconds. So we have to multiply the number of seconds by 1000.

```
<p id="count"></p>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = prompt("Enter your starting number");
    setInterval(function() {
        count += 1500000;
        $("#count").text(count);
    }, 86400000);
});
```

The maximum value for the delay is a signed 32 bit integer, which is equal to `2 ^ 32 - 1`. This represents a value of 4294967295 ms.

Comment: Thanks I neglected to mention that the client wants to add this information via WordPress as a Custom Field, which I have set up on that end